# Read access violation when inserting into unordered map

Tags: c++, templates, runtime-error

I am messing with [a small ECS implementation found here](https://github.com/hrhodin/tinyECS). I slowly copied the code to understand it and it works fine. However, instead of one big namespace, I'm trying to separate the functionality out into different classes and abstract everything with a "coordinator" class before I try to add the "system" part of ECS.

So I have something like this (sorry if my code is bad in advance, still learning C++):

```cpp
// ECSCoordinator.h

#ifndef I3D_ECS_COORDINATOR_H
#define I3D_ECS_COORDINATOR_H

#include <memory>
#include "Entity.h"
#include "EntityManager.h"

#include "ComponentContainer.h"

class ECSCoordinator {
public:
    ECSCoordinator();

    Entity create_entity();
    void delete_entity();

    template<typename Component>
    void add_component_to(Entity e, Component c);

private:
    template<class Component> 
    static ComponentContainer<Component> registry;
    std::unique_ptr<EntityManager> entity_manager;
};

template<typename Component>
void ECSCoordinator::add_component_to(Entity e, Component c) {
    registry<Component>.insert(e, c);
}

// ECSCoordinator.cpp

#include "ECSCoordinator.h"
#include "ECS/Entity.h"
#include "ECS/EntityManager.h"

ECSCoordinator::ECSCoordinator()
    : entity_manager(std::make_unique<EntityManager>()) {}

Entity ECSCoordinator::create_entity() {
    return entity_manager->create_entity();
}

#endif // I3D_ECS_COORDINATOR_H
```

One thing that I had to decide on was where to declare `registry`. In the original implementation it was declared in the scope of the namespace, but once I moved stuff into classes I didn't want to have a global variable just sitting there. So instead I made the variable template a static class member of the coordinator. I believe these are equivalent? The forward declaration of `ComponentContainer` then no longer worked since I'm defining `add_component_to` in the header, so I had to `#include "ComponentContainer.h"` instead, meaning I had to move the static definitions in `ComponentContainer` into their own .cpp file (if that matters).

Other than that, and making `Entity.h` a POD (holds just an unsigned int) and `EntityManager.h` responsible for creating an Entity with an incremented ID, I haven't changed much.

So when I want to use the system, I want to do this instead:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<ECSCoordinator> coordinator = std::make_unique<ECSCoordinator>();
Entity fish = coordinator->create_entity();
coordinator->add_component_to(fish, Animal("Fish"));
```

However, these changes cause a read access violation when I try to add a (key, value) to the unordered map (line 100 of tiny_ecs.hpp):

```cpp
map_entity_component_index[e.id] = component_index;
```

I can definitely confirm that `e.id = 0` and `component_index = 1` for the first addition. I can run a method on the unordered map like `size()` right before this error just fine. But, attempting to add something to the map causes a crash.

I'm not sure how to interpret the error I'm seeing in my debugger:

[image]

Thank you to anyone that helps.

Comment: What is `map_entity_component_index`? Where is it defined?

Comment: The comment on line 100 in `tiny_ecs.hpp` looks a bit bothering: `map_entity_component_index[e.id] = component_index; // Note, not using insert or emplace to allow inserting multiple components for the same entity (at your own risk)` - I wonder what "_at your own risk_" means.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm map_entity_component_index is a protected member in the class ComponentContainer inherits from.

Comment: It isn't defined anywhere, though, it is only declared. In the original implementation. a component for some entity is added to a registry by calling `registry<ComponentClass>.insert(entity, component)`, i.e. `registry<WaterAnimal>.insert(fish, WaterAnimal())`. I believe this implicitly instantiates `registry<WaterAnimal>`, of which a pointer is saved to on lines 76&77 (since registry is of type `ComponentContainer<Component>`, and `static std::vector<ContainerInterface*>` (see tiny_ecs.cpp) is a singleton with pointers of the class `ComponentContainer` inherits from).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being due to static order initialisation fiasco. The solution was to access the static template variable in the Coordinator via a getter to ensure its initialisation:

```
class ECSCoordinator {
    //....

    template<class Component>
    ComponentContainer<Component>& get_registry();

    //...
};

template<typename Component>
void ECSCoordinator::add_component_to(Entity e, Component c) {
    get_registry<Component>().insert(e, c);
}

template<class Component>
ComponentContainer<Component>& ECSCoordinator::get_registry() {
    static ComponentContainer<Component> registry;
    return registry;
}
```